# Limit Width Of The Buttons In CSS

Tags: css, button, width, limit

CSS:

```
.btn { 
background: #53A2FF;
border: 2px solid transparent;
color: #eee;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 9px 15px;
outline: none;
transition: 0.5s all;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s all;
-moz-transition: 0.5s all;
-o-transition: 0.5s all;
-ms-transition: 0.5s all;
}
.btn:hover { 
border: 2px solid #000;
background: transparent;
color: #000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button class="btn">Hello Over There!</button>
<br><br>
<button class="btn">This Button Has Too Much Text, That's Why It Is Bigger!</button>
<br><br>
<button class="btn">Hello Over There! This Is The Third Button!</button>
```

Output will be similar to:

[image: Buttons With Different Sizes]

Size of each button depends on the amount of letters.

If I change the HTML & do something like this.

```
<input class="btn" value="Hello Over There!">
<br><br>
<input class="btn" value="This Button Has Too Much Text, That's Why It Is Bigger!">
<br><br>
<input class="btn" value="Hello Over There! This Is The Third Button!">
```

So the output will be similar to:

[image: Buttons With Same Sizes]

Size of each button will be the same. But `input` tag is mainly used for HTML forms and using them for making links is not a good idea at all!

I tried to do this using CSS `max-width:`, but the text inside the button started overflowing.

If I want to use the `button` tag instead of the `input` tag, and if I want to limit the width of buttons, so which CSS code should I use?

I exactly want the same output of `input` tag while using the `button` tag.

Comment: @TemaniAfif What was the edit needed for? It's not like <br /> and <input /> are errors in HTML or something.

Comment: @MrLister i never said they are errors :) if it was the case i would comment ... they are simply unecessary and not needed when using HTML5

Comment: I don't think that's a good enough reason for changing it. Slashes are optional as per the specs, so why couldn't they stay in? Besides, how do we even know the OP's environment is HTML rather than XHTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with `max-width`, but you also need to 1) make sure the text doesn't wrap, using `white-space`, and 2) hide the extraneous characters with `overflow`.

```css
.btn {
  background: #53A2FF;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  color: #eee;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.5s all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s all;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s all;
  -o-transition: 0.5s all;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s all;
  /* so these are new: */
  max-width:20em;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.btn:hover {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background: transparent;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Hello Over There!</button>
<br><br>
<button class="btn">This Button Has Too Much Text, That's Why It Is Bigger!</button>
<br><br>
<button class="btn">Hello Over There! This Is The Third Button!</button>
```

Comment: In addition, you can use the title tag for showing the original text on hover.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai, I was confused until I realized you meant the `title=""` *attribute*. 

Answer (score 0):

```
.btn { 
display: inline-block;
font-size: 12px;
background: #53A2FF;
border: 2px solid transparent;
color: #eee;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 3px 2px;
width: 250px;
outline: none;
transition: 0.5s all;
-webkit-transition: 0.5s all;
-moz-transition: 0.5s all;
-o-transition: 0.5s all;
-ms-transition: 0.5s all;
}
.btn:hover { 
border: 2px solid #000;
background: transparent;
color: #000;
}
```

Try this if it works for you.. by width attribute you can specify your width of your button in css